# How can I open a popup window with a fixed size using the HREF tag?

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I have a link like this:

```
$contact_url = "<a href=rentals_popup.php?id=$row->rentals_id >" . "Contact" . "</a>";
```

How can I open that page in a different window with?

*Smaller width and height*

*Disabled maximize button*

Comment: Disabling the maximize button seems overly limiting and downright rude to your users. What, I can stretch it until it fills the screen, but I can't let the operating system do it for me?

Answer (score 28):

This should work

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('document.aspx','mywindowtitle','width=500,height=150')">open window</a>
```

Comment: It work's, but the current page redirect to javascript:window.open('document.aspx','mywindowtitle','width=500,height=150 ..... and shows "[object Window]"

Answer (score 7):

Plain HTML does not support this. You'll need to use some JavaScript code.

Also, note that large parts of the world are using a popup blocker nowadays. You may want to reconsider your design!

Comment: Oh. Nice Suggestion. Thanks Thomas. But my requirement is that i want small window or dialog open and in that my php file should be shown

Answer (score 4):

Since many browsers block popups by default and popups are really ugly, I recommend using lightbox or thickbox.

They are prettier and are not popups. They are extra HTML markups that are appended to your document's body with the appropriate CSS content.

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on [Esben Skov Pedersen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693222/how-can-i-open-a-popup-window-with-a-fixed-size-using-the-href-tag/1693247#1693247) directly, but using the following notation for links:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.websiteofyourchoice.com');">Click here</a>
```

In Internet Explorer, the new browser window appears, but the current window navigates to a page which says "[Object]". To avoid this, simple put a "void(0)" behind the JavaScript function.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257321

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (*"Sorry, page not found"*).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a `div` element pop-up window that contains an iframe.

[jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is a simple way to get started. Just [add an iframe as the content](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/jQuery-UI-Dialog-w-Resizable-iFrame.aspx).